# HTML/Javascript Calculator

Tags: javascript, html

I am taking a WebGIS lecture this semester and could use some assistance with debugging my code. It's a very simple HTML/js calculator, but it's giving me issues. None of the buttons are displaying any numbers or executing any functions in my js code. Could anyone give me a hand with figuring out what's wrong? I'm sure it's a simple fix, but the cones in my retinas are burning out trying to find it.

Thank you!

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>Calculator!</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="calculator.js"></script>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">
                <input type="text" id="txtTotal" name="txtTotal" value="0"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">
                <input type="text" id="txtTrai" name="txtTrail" disabled='true' value="0"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="button" id="btnl" name="bnt1" value="1" onclick="nextVal(1);" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" id="btn2" name="bnt2" value="2" onclick="nextVal(2);" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" id="btn3" name="bnt3" value="3" onclick="nextVal(3);" />
            </td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="button" id="btn4" name="bnt4" value="4" onclick="nextVal(4);" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" id="btn5" name="bnt5" value="5" onclick="nextVal(5);" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" id="btn6" name="bnt6" value="6" onclick="nextVal(6);" />
            </td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="button" id="btn7" name="bnt7" value="7" onclick="nextVal(7);" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" id="btn8" name="bnt8" value="8" onclick="nextVal(8);" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" id="btn9" name="bnt9" value="9" onclick="nextVal(9);" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" id="clear" name="clear" value="C" onclick="clearCalc()" />
            </td>   
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="button" id="plus" name="plus" value="+" onclick="setFunction('plus');" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" id="btn0" name="btn0" value="0" onclick="nextVal(0);" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" id="minus" name="minus" value="-" onclick="setFunction('minus');" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" id="equal" name="equal" value="=" onclick="sum();" />
            </td>   
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var total = 0;
var funct = '';

function nextVal(1) {
    var txtTotal = document.getElementById('txtTotal');
    txtTotal.value = 1;
    var txtTrail = document.getElementById('txtTrail');

    if (funct == 'plus') {
        total += 1;
        txtTrail.value += ' ' + 1;
    }
    else if (funct == 'minus'); {
        total -= 1;
        txtTrail.value += ' ' + 1;
    }
    else {
        total = 1;
        txtTrail.value = 1;
    }
}

function nextVal(2) {
    var txtTotal = document.getElementById('txtTotal');
    txtTotal.value = 2;
    var txtTrail = document.getElementById('txtTrail');

    if (funct == 'plus') {
        total += 2;
        txtTrail.value += ' ' + 2;
    }
    else if (funct == 'minus'); {
        total -= 2;
        txtTrail.value += ' ' + 2;
    }
    else {
        total = 2;
        txtTrail.value = 2;
    }
}

function nextVal(3) {
    var txtTotal = document.getElementById('txtTotal');
    txtTotal.value = 3;
    var txtTrail = document.getElementById('txtTrail');

    if (funct == 'plus') {
        total += 3;
        txtTrail.value += ' ' + 3;
    }
    else if (funct == 'minus'); {
        total -= 3;
        txtTrail.value += ' ' + 3;
    }
    else {
        total = 3;
        txtTrail.value = 3;
    }
}

function nextVal(4) {
    var txtTotal = document.getElementById('txtTotal');
    txtTotal.value = 4;
    var txtTrail = document.getElementById('txtTrail');

    if (funct == 'plus') {
        total += 4;
        txtTrail.value += ' ' + 4;
    }
    else if (funct == 'minus'); {
        total -= 4;
        txtTrail.value += ' ' + 4;
    }
    else {
        total = 4;
        txtTrail.value = 4;
    }
}

function nextVal(5) {
    var txtTotal = document.getElementById('txtTotal');
    txtTotal.value = 5;
    var txtTrail = document.getElementById('txtTrail');

    if (funct == 'plus') {
        total += 5;
        txtTrail.value += ' ' + 5;
    }
    else if (funct == 'minus'); {
        total -= 5;
        txtTrail.value += ' ' + 5;
    }
    else {
        total = 5;
        txtTrail.value = 5;
    }
}

function nextVal(6) {
    var txtTotal = document.getElementById('txtTotal');
    txtTotal.value = 6;
    var txtTrail = document.getElementById('txtTrail');

    if (funct == 'plus') {
        total += 6;
        txtTrail.value += ' ' + 6;
    }
    else if (funct == 'minus'); {
        total -= 6;
        txtTrail.value += ' ' + 6;
    }
    else {
        total = 6;
        txtTrail.value = 6;
    }
}

function nextVal(7) {
    var txtTotal = document.getElementById('txtTotal');
    txtTotal.value = 7;
    var txtTrail = document.getElementById('txtTrail');

    if (funct == 'plus') {
        total += 7;
        txtTrail.value += ' ' + 7;
    }
    else if (funct == 'minus'); {
        total -= 7;
        txtTrail.value += ' ' + 7;
    }
    else {
        total = 7;
        txtTrail.value = 7;
    }
}

function nextVal(8) {
    var txtTotal = document.getElementById('txtTotal');
    txtTotal.value = 8;
    var txtTrail = document.getElementById('txtTrail');

    if (funct == 'plus') {
        total += 8;
        txtTrail.value += ' ' + 8;
    }
    else if (funct == 'minus'); {
        total -= 8;
        txtTrail.value += ' ' + 8;
    }
    else {
        total = 8;
        txtTrail.value = 8;
    }
}

function nextVal(9) {
    var txtTotal = document.getElementById('txtTotal');
    txtTotal.value = 9;
    var txtTrail = document.getElementById('txtTrail');

    if (funct == 'plus') {
        total += 9;
        txtTrail.value += ' ' + 9;
    }
    else if (funct == 'minus'); {
        total -= 9;
        txtTrail.value += ' ' + 9;
    }
    else {
        total = 9;
        txtTrail.value = 9;
    }
}

function nextVal(0) {
    var txtTotal = document.getElementById('txtTotal');
    txtTotal.value = 0;
    var txtTrail = document.getElementById('txtTrail');

    if (funct == 'plus') {
        total += 0;
        txtTrail.value += ' ' + 0;
    }
    else if (funct == 'minus'); {
        total -= 0;
        txtTrail.value += ' ' + 0;
    }
    else {
        total = 0;
        txtTrail.value = 0;
    }
}

function setFunction(f) {
    var txtTrail = document.getElementById('txtTrail');
    funct = f;

    if (funct == 'true') {
        txt.Trail.value += ' +';
    }
    else if (funct == 'minus') {
        txt.Trail.value -= ' -';
    }
}

function sum() {
    var txtTotal = document.getElementById('txtTotal');
    if (txtTotal) {
        txtTotal.value = total;
    }

function clearCalc() {
    var txtTotal = document.getElementById('txtTotal');
    txtTotal.value = 0;

    var txtTrail =document.getElementById('txtTrail');
    txtTotal.value = 0;

    total = 0;
    funct = '';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Went ahead and changed everything; still no luck.

Comment: Here's a little something to get you started. [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZHHX2/1/). If I weren't busy atm, I'd have given you a fully working version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can I make a few recommendations?

You should have one JS method that captures all input values from the calculator.  I would event propagation here, set the onclick handler on the parent instead of each element.  In this method look at the target and add to the display.  This is a better and cleaner approach then adding the inline onclick handlers with a preset parameter.

Also you don't need to have a unique nextVal Function for every key.  Just pass this in as a parameter or set a data-attr value on the key and grab the value in your single handler.

Wire up this event handler by binding to a single class.  Assign each key to the same class (e.g. input-value).  If you decide not to use event propagation - you can also bind an onclick handler to every element with this class.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance as I'm only a week into Javascript, but how would I go about doing that? I agree, the code looks awfully messy with multiple nextVal functions, but I'm at a loss on how I would be able to condense them. I looked up bubbling/event propagation, but it's all way over my head.

Comment: @Bradley_Jay Essentially what he's saying is redo your project, haha. Try looking at an existing calculator project, it may give you an idea how

Comment: Ah, okay. I'm hesitant to rewrite it only because my lab TA gave us some of the outlines for functions that he would expect to see from beginners like me. Not sure if rewriting w/ code we didn't learn in lab will impact my grade negatively.

Comment: @Newse: Although all these are good suggestions on their own, I'd suggest that taken together they are not appropriate for the level of the poster.  It would be interesting to see a blog post that took this code and modernized it one step at a time.  But the OP was looking for a more simple answer to a "Why doesn't this work?"

Comment: Check this out - I reworked your code a little bit to get the basic concept working:  http://jsfiddle.net/rnewsome/3LJuh/

Comment: @ScottSauyet - having all of the duplicate methods that serve the exact same purpose is not necessary (and not a good practice).  I changed two things:  all input keys call the same method (passing in the parameter).  This is really the change that needed to happen.  Optionally, I used jquery to wire up the click event in an non-invasive approach.

Comment: @Newse Thank you for taking the time to rewrite it. I was not familiar with some of the code that you wrote, so I had to Google some of it to get an idea of what was happening. The only problem is that we haven't dabbled around in JQuery, so if I were to include that in this assignment, it would probably raise my TA's eyebrows.

Comment: @Newse: I'm sure we both could write this code in substantially better ways than the OP.  But that's not really the point.  Not only does it not answer the original question, but it doesn't help the poster learn to write better code.  I would recommend suggesting smaller changes, even if that doesn't lead to code as elegant as possible.  Also, introducing jQuery here just to handle a little minor event processing, seems overkill.

Comment: @ScottSauyet - you raise some good points - small steps is good advice.  I think not having redundant code is a good general practice, agnostic to any particular language.  Was just trying to help.

Comment: @Bradley_Jay - I changed it back to use the event handling the way you had it.   http://jsfiddle.net/rnewsome/3LJuh/2/  Please let me know if you have any questions

Comment: @Newse: And I think you were helping.  I was just suggesting that it would be more helpful to take it a bit slower.  :-)

Comment: @Newse I'm taking a look at it right now. I'll reply with any questions I have. :) Thank you.

Comment: @Newse I'm currently trying to get the 'C' and '=' buttons functioning correctly. I've tried & failed at adding the '=' to the switch statement and the 'C' to the if/else statement. Any advice?

Comment: @Bradley_Jay - try this http://jsfiddle.net/rnewsome/3LJuh/7/ I broke out Clear and Sum into their own functions.

Comment: @Newse Thank you! I do have one more question, though: Is there any reason why, in the lastOperator variable, a + sign is there? I left it blank and didn't notice any difference in the program.

Comment: @Bradley_Jay - I put it together quick, you may not need it.  The concept I was going for was a default operator incase the user just started typing numbers without specifying an operator.  So by default it would start adding numbers.  Glad to help - if it works out for you please send an up vote my way.

Comment: @Newse It was a big help; thanks again. :) I tried giving you an upvote, but I don't have '15' reputation, whatever that is. :(

Answer (score 0):

The big problem right now is that you can't have multiple functions with the same name:

```
// This makes no sense
function nextVal(1) { ... }
function nextVal(2) { ... }
// ...
```

You could change it to this:

```
function nextVal1() { ... }
function nextVal2() { ... }
// ...
```

There are many other things that could be done to this code, as Newse pointed out, but start with that...

### Update

A second problem is the (many) lines like this:

```
else if (funct == 'minus'); {
   //                     ^
   // this semicolon      |
   // doesn't belong -----+
```

That semicolon ends the statement, and hence the `{ }` delimited section doesn't act as you expect.

There is also a missing end-brace for the `sum` function, and finally, the id for the `txtTrail` element is misspelled.  Fixing all of those, will, I think, get you to a **[working state](http://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/9RrGs/)**.

---

But the points Newse is making in his answer, and similarly the ones in akinuri's Fiddle are  quite important in developing your programming skills.

This code is extremely repetitive.   One of the important maxims of programming is to keep your code DRY -- **D** on't **R** epeat **Y** ourself.  There are any number of simple techniques which would help to remove the repetition in this code.

Also, many would object on similar grounds to the multiple event handlers you attach.  There are techniques such as event delegation that would help clean this up.

Some of these techniques will come as a matter of course during your time programming.  But the best way to speed them along is to keep a constant critical eye on your own work, asking yourself always, "How could I have done this better?"

The Fiddle posted above is not code an advanced developer would be proud of.  But it's a working start.  So my challenge to you now is: what can you do to improve it?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I went ahead and rewrote all the functions to what you recommended in your post, and changed the onclick's accordingly. Still no dice.

Could this be an issue with the Javascript and HTML files not playing nicely with each other? I think I linked the .js correctly in the .html file, and both of them are in the same folder on my desktop.

Comment: If you're not familiar with the debugging consoles, in most browsers, you can launch them by pressing F12.  You should probably check the Javascript console for any errors if you haven't done so yet.  Another possibility is to post the code on **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)**, **[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/)**, **[Codepen](http://codepen.io/)**, **[Plunkr](http://codepen.io/)**, or some similar sandbox site.  This give people the chance to see how their suggested changes might or might not actually help.